# "Unimplemented File Type" while using DMTCP and MPICH

Tags: mpi

I'm following DMTCP's guide to run MPI applications (both NPB benchmarks and a simple Hello World application failed) with it. However, I'm getting an "Message: Unimplemented file type" whenever I try to run any MPI application.
I tested it with non-MPI and it worked perfectly. I'm using ubuntu22.04, MPICH version 4.0 and DMTCP 2.6, from the git repo.

This is the error message:

```
[2023-12-06T00?35:45.380, 4200, 4200, Error] at fileconnlist.cpp:727 in processFileConnection; REASON='JASSERT(false) failed'
path = sr0
Message: Unimplemented file type.
is.A.x: Terminating...
Backtrace:
1 _ZN16jassert_internal7JAssertD2Ev in /usr/local/lib/dmtcp/libdmtcp.so 0x7f15239b68c4
2 _ZN5dmtcp12FileConnList21processFileConnectionEiPKcij in /usr/local/lib/dmtcp/libdmtcp_ipc.so 0x7f1523a635df
3 _ZN5dmtcp13PluginManager9eventHookE11eDmtcpEventP17_)DmtcpEventData_t in /usr/local/lib/dmtcp/libdmtcp.so 0x7f15239813b8
4 in /usr/local/lib/dmtcp/libdmtcp.so 0x7152398c161
5 openat64 in /usr/local/lib/dmtcp/libdmtcp.so.1 0x7f1520c0f8e4
6 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdev.so.1 0x7f81ac31f8e4
7 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdev.so.1 0x7f81ac30b5ff
8 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdev.so.1 0x7f81ac30bb6b
9 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdev.so.1 0x7f81ac30fcbd
10 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdev.so.1 0x7f81ac31ed55
11 udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 0x781ac30c27f
12 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.15 0x7f81ac4c26c9
13 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.15 0x7f81ac4c493f
14 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.15 0x7f81ac4bc2fb
15 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.15 0x7f81ac31ed55
16 hwloc_topology_load in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwloc.so.15 0x7f81ac494b31
17 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12 0x7f81aeb6b3a6
18 MPI_Init in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12 0x7f81acb1f7ee
19 in ./bin/is.A.x 0x55a33d7e93fd
20 in /lib/x95_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 0x7f81ac83dd90
21 __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 0x7f81ac83de40
22 in ./bin/is.A.x 0x55a33d7e9b55
```

I already had issued dmtcp_coordinator on a first terminal, and in the second I tried:

```
dmtcp_launch --join-coordinator mpirun ./bin/is.A.x
```

The code I tried to execute here is a NPB benchmark of class is.